# Related to share point back up and restore from 2003 version to 2013 version

Tags: backup

I am very new in share point and i have a task to take complete backup of share point server 2003 to another server 2013 so i have done the backup process with share point server 2003 but when i restore it in share point 2013 so i am facing many problem very first problem is that it shows that farm version is different. So please any one know about the solution of my problem so just inform me.

Answer (score -1):

their is no direct way to migrate from SharePoint 2003 to SharePoint 2013.
Now you have two options.

Method # 1

1. You have create sharepoint 2007, SharePoint 2010 and sharepoint 2013 Farms. As i said you cannot migrate it directly. So you have to 1st migrate to 2007 then 2010 finally in 2013.

Method # 2

- Use the 3rd party tools i.e ShareGate, metalogiz etc. In this case you dont need 2007 & 2010 farm, these tools support direct migration.

Another way is manually move all content to SharePoint 2013 farms.